# Outlook Add-in API displayForwardForm Office JS

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Is there an equivalent to displayReplyForm under Office.context.mailbox.item (Office-js) in order to display forward form to the user?

My goal is to open a Forward form for the user with the 'to' field already filled, I need the original item, therefor create new item (displayNewMessageForm e.g) will not help.

I am aware of the option to use the REST-API in order to forward the event but due to the fact it is required ReadWriteMailbox (instead of ReadWriteItem) it is not possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the feature displayForwardForm, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.